# concat list and sum it in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists `L1` and `L2`:

```
L1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L2 = [1,2]
```

I want to make list `L3` from `L1` and `L2`:

```
L3 =  [3,5,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I made a function, but it wont work:

```
def mapp():
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        try:
            L3.append(L2[i] + L1[i])
        except:
            L3.append(L1[i])
    return L3'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you edit your question to correct the formating please ?

Comment: Can you explain why your function doesn't work? I edited the question to the best I could parse but currently it seems to work assuming `L1` is the longer list. The bigger problem is that your lists are global.

Comment: I was curious about your answer
I rewrote the code and it works well..
i can use if else for different len list, not just L1 is the longer but L2 too

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to take two lists (L1 and L2) and sum the elements with matching index . You can do that this way :

```
def mapp(L1,L2):
    #we make sure the first list is always the longest
    if len(L1)<len(L2):
        L1,L2 = L2,L1
    #we copy the longest list
    L3=L1.copy()
    #we add the short list elements to the long list elements
    for i,n in enumerate(L2):
        L3[i]+=n
    return L3

print(mapp(L1=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],L2=[1,2]))
```

Output : `[3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`